# Syntax error code - Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, syntax-error

Normally My code is working fine. but, I get Syntax error. what is mistake in syntax here?

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.myClass').change(function() {
        var ids = ['first', 'second'];
        var totalCount = ids.reduce((prev, id) => parseInt($(`#${id}-passenger`).val()) + prev, 0);
        var mc = $('input[name="myClass"]:checked  + label').text();
        $('#myTotal').val(totalCount + ' - '+mc);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to add `'` not `

Comment: Your code is fine. Most likely the issue is that the linter used in your IDE is outdated so doesn't recognised ES6 standards such as template literals and arrow functions

Comment: @dekts No, backticks are used to delimit template literals and are valid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @dekts I have replace it. but, thought, error is still. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have a Javascript version issue and you should try without templating ?

```
var totalCount = ids.reduce(function (prev, id) {
    return parseInt($('#' + id + '-passenger').val()) + prev
}, 0);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's done for the arrows :) But I think my brackets are fine ?

Comment: You're right - my bad. I read the syntax incorrectly in the OP

Answer (score 1):

Your code is entirely valid and works fine. Therefore I would surmise that this issue is simply that the JS linter in the IDE you're using is outdated and doesn't support ES6. I'd suggest using a more up to date linter, assuming the IDE lets you change it, or even a better IDE entirely.

If you want to avoid the issue you would need to remove the template literals and arrow functions, like this:

```
$('.myClass').change(function() {
  var ids = ['first', 'second'];
  var totalCount = ids.reduce(function(prev, id) {
    return parseInt($('#' + id + '-passenger').val()) + prev, 10);
  }, 0);
  var mc = $('input[name="myClass"]:checked + label').text();
  $('#myTotal').val(totalCount + ' - ' + mc);
});
```